# django password_change noreversematch

Tags: python, django, authentication, passwords

I'm new to Django, and I'm trying add user authentication to a simple app.  I'm working with Django 1.9, and I'm trying to do this a simply as possible.  Login and Logout work, but with "Change Password", I get a NoReverseMatch error for password_change_done.

From my urls.py

```
app_name = 'league'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

In /league/templates/league/index.html, I have:

```
<a href="{% url 'league:login' %}">Login</a>
<a href="{% url 'league:logout' %}">Logout</a>
<a href="{% url 'league:password_change' %}">Change Password</a>
<a href="{% url 'league:password_change_done' %}">Change Password Done</a>
```

I created these files in /league/templates/registration/.  password_change_form.html and password_change_done.html currently do nothing, they contain only a string that gets displayed.

- login.html
- logged_out.html
- password_change_form.html
- password_change_done.html

When I click the "Change Password" link, I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /league/password_change/
Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments'()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I know the "Change Password Done" link is silly, but I added it to see what happens.  It works fine.  When I click it, password_change_done.html displays, as expected.

Here's the stack trace from when I click the "Change Password" link:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/league/password_change/

Django Version: 1.9.2
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
['league.apps.LeagueConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in inner
  49.         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in password_change
  308.         post_change_redirect = reverse('password_change_done')

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  600.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/home/mriley/.virtualenvs/django1_8/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  508.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /league/password_change/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I found similar cases on stackoverflow, including [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609310/noreversematch-at-reverse-for-password-change-done-with-arguments-and-k)

I changed my urls.py to this:

```
url(r'^password_change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    {'current_app': 'league'},
    name='password_change'),
url(r'^password_change_done/$',
    auth_views.password_change_done,
    {'current_app': 'league'},
    name='password_change_done'),
```

But it made no difference, I still get the NoReverseMatch error.

Any ideas what I'm doing incorrectly with "Change Password"?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `password_change` view [does not use](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L346) the `current_app` parameter to determine the redirect url. You need to explicitly pass the view name including the namespace:

```
url(r'^password_change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    {'post_change_redirect': 'league:password_change_done'},
    name='password_change'),
```

The `current_app` parameter is only used in the `{% url %}` tag in the template, but it is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#current-app-parameter-to-contrib-auth-views) and will be removed in Django 2.0. If you need the current app in the template context, you need to set `request.current_app`.

Comment: That got me going, thanks!  I added the URL declaration for password_change_done, and it worked perfectly.